# AttributeError: 'LoginForm' object has no attribute 'validate_on_sumbit'

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I have done a registration and login page registration page works fine but login page when i Click on create account i get object has no attribute.

application.py

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField,PasswordField,SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import Length,EqualTo,InputRequired,ValidationError
from models import User
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

def login():
    login_form = LoginForm()
    if login_form.validate_on_sumbit():
        return "Logged in, finally!"
    return render_template('login.html', form=login_form)
#wtform_fields.py
class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    """Login Form """

    username = StringField('username_label',validators=[InputRequired(message="username required")])
    password = PasswordField('password_label',validators=[InputRequired(message="Password required"),invalid_credentials])
    submit   = SubmitField('Login')
```

login.html

```
{% from 'form_helper.html' import DisplayField %}

{% extends "prelogin-layout.html" %}

{% block title %} Registration {% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <h3>Create your account</h3>
    <hr>
    <form action="{{ url_for('index') }}", method="POST" >
       {{DisplayField(form.username, 'Username', autocomplete='off',autofocus=true)}}
       {{DisplayField(form.password, 'Password')}}
       {{DisplayField(form.confirm, 'Confirm Password')}}
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" >
        </div>
        {{form.csrf_token}}
    </form>
   
   
  
{% endblock %}
```

ErrorLog

```
in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "C:\Users\Catalyst\Desktop\Python\chatAp\application.py", line 18, in login
    if login_form.validate_on_sumbit():
AttributeError: 'LoginForm' object has no attribute 'validate_on_sumbit'
```

I'm new at flask can you direct e where I'm mistaken
**PS I'm working with flaskwtf V1.0.1**

Comment: Do you mean `validate_on_submit`?

Comment: what is in your 'login.html'?

Comment: @WanderNauta yeah

Comment: @DanielKanzel I have edtied the post with login.html

Comment: @Arthur, and add, please, error log :)

Comment: @WanderNauta has it.. you spelled `sumbit` instead of `submit` in `application.py`

Comment: aah it was front of my eyes all the time thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line that adds submit in login.html from

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" >
        </div>
```

to

```
        <div class="form-group">
            {{DisplayField(form.submit, 'Create')}}
        </div>
```

If you are using Flask WTF all fields in the form must come from the library.

P.S.
I don't know where you got the confirm variable to check the password from.
It may not work for you either. If you want the user to enter the password twice, read here: [wtforms.validators.EqualTo](https://If%20you%20want%20the%20user%20to%20enter%20the%20password%20twice,%20read%20here:)

Comment: I have already done that for registration page confirmation password works fine but when I added login page it gives me error on  login_form.validate_on_sumbit()

Comment: Trie this, change ```if login_form.validate_on_sumbit(): ``` to ``` if request.method=='POST':``` and add this ```from flask import request```.

Comment: it worked thanks but why validate_on_submit didn't works if you may asking

Comment: It is related to the library version. There are FLASK-WTF and WTForms. This is the same library but different versions. You use WTForms.
WTForms - https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/
Flask-WTF - https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.x/